# pycharm can't connect to mysql in Azure

Tags: mysql, database, azure, pycharm

i can't connect to mysql server on Azure via pychrm even thought i am able to connect tot it via mysql cmd an mysql-worbench so there is no connection problem between my vm and the azure mysql server . 
my configuration:
[image: data sources and drivers]

Answer (score 0):

If you try with the default url, it throws the error message as "[08001] Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up."

```
jdbc:mysql://azuremysql.mysql.database.azure.com:3306
```

[image]

If you want to connect 5.6 & 5.7 version of MySQL JDBC driver to work with UTC time zone, one has to specify the **`serverTimezone` explicitly in the connection string**.

**Try this as url:**

```
jdbc:mysql://azuremysql.mysql.database.azure.com:3306?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

[image]

Comment: sorry i did all that and still not connected

Comment: When you say "Still not connected", could you please share the error message?

Comment: Connection to my_user failed.
[08001] Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

Comment: Have you downloaded the missing driver files?

Comment: Kindly check the updated answer and do let us know, if that works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195118/discussion-between-cheekatlapradeep-msft-and-junior-software).